# Update a list of a list of elements in a single list?

Tags: list, listview, haskell, replace

I have some code which is designed to replace a value in a list

```
replaceNth n newVal (x:xs)
 | n == 0 = newVal:xs
 | otherwise = x:replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs
```

For example, when I load the function into GHCI, I enter and get the following:

```
*Main> replaceNth 3 4 [3,3,3,3,3]
[3,3,3,4,3]
```

However I am trying to use this function for a multiple lists within a list and can't seem to do so (e.g.).

What I want is to get a result like this:

```
[[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,**2**,3],[3,3,3,3,3]]
```

From this [[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3]]

using something like the function above.

Comment: The  type of this list replacement function is subtly different to your original replace function, since it now replaces elements 2 levels deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this does what you want (applied to the list of lists):

`replaceNth 1 (replaceNth 3 4 [3,3,3,3,3])`

Comment: Dear Sir, your attitude is good, but your code won't compile.

Comment: It's too specific for something generic.

Comment: @Jakob Runge: My "code" is a function - so it won't yield an exe, if you mean that -- but applied to a list of lists it yields a list of lists.

Comment: Outch - my fail: I had a type error in my mind concerning replaceNth :: (Num a) => a -> a1 -> [a1] -> [a1] aka on first thought it appeared to me, that a1 must have been instance of Num, which is nonsense. -> Ashes on my head, your code is quite a simple solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not general enough to handle the task you wish it to preform.  In particular, you need to know what the replacement value will be *before* you call the function.  To get this working you might either:

- Select the nth list, compute the new list then use your function to put that replacement in the list of lists.  **OR** (and better)
- Make a more general function that instead of taking a new value takes a function from the old value to the new:

**Example**

```
replaceNth' :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
replaceNth' n f (x:xs)
  | n == 0 = (f x):xs
  | otherwise = x:replace (n-1) f xs
```

Now to solve you second problem:

```
let ls = [[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3]]
in replaceNth' 1 (replaceNth' 3 (const 2)) ls
```

That is replace the second list with a list made by taking the fourth element of that list and replacing what ever it is with 2.

Answer (score 2):

Make a function that applies a function to the nth element of a list instead.  Then you can easily get what you want by composing that with itself and using const for the inner replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing definition:

```
ghci> let arg = [[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,3,3]]
ghci> replaceNth 1 (replaceNth 3 2 (arg !! 1)) arg
[[3,3,3,3,3],[3,3,3,2,3],[3,3,3,3,3]]
ghci>
```

To refactor it into a function:

```
replaceMthNth m n v arg = replaceNth m (replaceNth n v (arg !! m)) arg
```

Comment: Thanks, but would be great if it could be mapped into a function.

Comment: @maclunian: that's easy.  Just pull out the bits you want the function to vary over.