# Updating a list of elements within a list?

Tags: list, haskell, ghci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update a list of a list of elements in a single list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860482/update-a-list-of-a-list-of-elements-in-a-single-list)

I have a list of values as shown below:

```
[ ["Off","Off","Off"],
  ["Off","Off","Off"],
  ["Off","Off","Off"] ]
```

and would like to return the following:

```
[ ["Off","Off","Off"],
  ["Off",*"On"*,"Off"],
  ["Off","Off","Off"] ]
```

I have the following function which works just for an individual list by itself:

```
replaceAll 0 newValue (x:xs) = newValue:xs
replaceAll b newValue (x:xs) = x:replaceAll (b-1) newValue xs
```

However, I seem to be having trouble working with these multiple lists within a list. How would I devise a function to deal with these two lists (i.e. a list inside another list)?

Still trying to get my head around the whole (x:xs) thing.

Comment: Not really, I don't believe I asked the right question, sorry.

Comment: the normal approach is to edit your original question (perhaps by bottom-posting updates and refinements), rather than post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists aren't the best structure for this sort of thing. But let's work with lists anyway.

We'll tweak your `replaceAll` so that instead of you providing the replacement value, you provide a function that specifies how to replace the old one with the new one.

```
replaceAll 0 f (x:xs) = f x:xs -- Here's where we transform x using f
replaceAll b f (x:xs) = x:replaceAll (b-1) f xs
```

Now we can use `replaceAll` on itself to perform the replacement we want on a specific row of the matrix:

```
test = replaceAll 1 (replaceAll 1 (const "On")) yourList
```

The `const "On"` function is used because when we get to our specific element we no longer want to transform it, we just want to replace it with `"On"`. Bit for each individual row we *do* want to transform it.

Comment: I'm all ears if you have a better suggestion!

Comment: @maclunian Notice how when you change the middle of a row you have to rebuild the entire list to the left of the element. There are structures that don't need you to rebuild so much stuff. But which you need depends on what problem you're solving. Maybe you want an IntMap? http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.1.0.1/doc/html/Data-IntMap.html